# Find a Twitter mention using Regex in Java (with a twist)

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a regex pattern to find mentions in a class called Tweets.
In this case, the valid characters after the '@' are: (A-Z or a-z), digits, underscore ("_"), or hyphen ("-").
The difference with classic Twitter usernames is that pattern should allow @--- or @___ or @00000, but also, when the char before '@' or after the name is not in the valid character list it should return the mention as valid (so not only white-spaces).

Strings like:

$$$$$@john$$$$$$ or %%%%@john%%%

should find @john as a valid mention since % isn't a valid name.

@@@@@john@@@@@ should also return @john.

Using http://regexr.com/ I created this pattern:

`@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*`

which in the mentioned page passes most requirements except @@@@john@@@ and richard@gmail.com which should ignore (since it has richard before) but instead turns into @gmail.

After that I improved this pattern

`(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]))@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+`

Tested in the same page (and also this one to verify results: http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html)
Not sure why this page shows results that my code doesn't.
I include my Java implementation just in case:

```
Set<String> users = new HashSet<>(); // to avoid repeated mentions
    for (Tweet t: tweets){
        String line = t.getText();
        String pattern = "(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]))@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find()){
            users.add(m.group().toLowerCase()); 
        }
```

And these are my test cases (all should return a mention except last two):

```
@tony
$$@yahoo$$
john @john john
@joules-
@john-cassidy
%%@jake%%
@@@jake@@@
dude$@jake$$
$$$@jack$$$
@@@jake@@@ 
@john4 
@jake2$
@johN3 
@rock-smith
@John 
@gmail.com //should not return but does: wrong
richard@mit.edu //should not find and it doesn't: good
```

From what I understand this: **(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-*\.]))*** is the *lookbehind* and I'm lacking the *lookahead* (not sure how to lookahead AFTER the valid chars) and cant understand the explanation about lookahead at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html to allow these chars: **[A-Za-z0-9-]** but not the rest (to ignore the match @gmail.com and avoid @gmail as return) .

Thanks in advance for your help. I have just 6 months in Java so this is the second time I use Regex and this feels like a complex one.

Comment: Because it assumes the user made a mistake (like inserting a whitespace in his email before the @) and the dot isnt a valid username character (however % or & after username doesnt make the match invalid)

Comment: The pattern should consider that if the text is " my email is john @gmail.com thnx" (notice the space) or "my email is john@gmail.com thnx" (at)gmail is not considered a mention, but if text is "I love to chat with @john&@jake" john and jake are mentions. " hi @@@@jake@@@@" should return (at)jake (sorry, Stack is detecting my mentions) so i replace it with (at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding positive lookahead to the end of original regex should help:

(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-*\.]))@[A-Za-z0-9*-]+**(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.])**

Comment: It works! gmail.com isn't considered a gmail mention

Comment: ``@john @john @john`` only links the first instance.